# Multiple Jquery UI Slider non linear value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, uislider

I have been searching and trying to find a solution for this but unfortunately can't get my way round it. I have multiple jQuery UI sliders which all have their values on sliding from an array. At the end I am trying to get the value of the slider and add it up with the other sliders. Here is the code for only two sliders:

```
$(function () {
    var labelArr = new Array(0, 200, 400, 600);
    $("#slider").slider({
        values: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: labelArr.length - 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            mbdata = labelArr[ui.value] + $("#slider_2").slider("value") + $("#slider_3").slider("value") + $("#slider_4").slider("value") + $("#slider_5").slider("value") + $("#slider_6").slider("value");
            g1.refresh(mbdata);
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    var labelArr = new Array(0, 300, 900, 1200);
    $("#slider_2").slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: labelArr.length - 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            mbdata = labelArr[ui.value] + $("#slider_3").slider("value") + $("#slider").slider("value") + $("#slider_4").slider("value") + $("#slider_5").slider("value") + $("#slider_6").slider("value");
            g1.refresh(mbdata);
        }
    });
});
```

The first slider works good, but unfortunately when I slide the second one the values are not showing the array ones but simply 1 , 2 , 3

Can someone please try giving me some help

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the whole script, but hopefully its doing now what you want it to do - just extend the sliderRangesValues Array (and add a new div with the right ID) to add more slider and values. Its now a much more flexible script:

http://jsfiddle.net/fKUAe/1/

Dummy HTML:

```
<div id="slider0" class="slider"></div>
<div id="slider1" class="slider"></div>
<div id="slider2" class="slider"></div>
<input type="text" id="slidervalues" value="0" />
```

jQuery:

```
var sliderRangeValues = [
    [0, 100, 200, 300],
    [0, 300, 600, 900],
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
];

function getAllSliderValues(sliderCount) {
    var sliderValues = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderCount; i++) {
        var uiValue = $('#slider' + i).slider('value');
        sliderValues += sliderRangeValues[i][uiValue];
    }
    $('#slidervalues').val(sliderValues);
}

function initSlider(i, sliderCount) {
    $('#slider' + i).slider({
        values: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: sliderRangeValues[i].length - 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $('#slider' + i).slider('value', ui.value);
            getAllSliderValues(sliderCount);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    var sliderCount = $('.slider').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderCount; i++) {
        initSlider(i, sliderCount);
    }
});
```

Comment: MANY MANY MANY Thanks :)) much appreciated. How can I call all the sliders and do a reset button ? and places all the the handles with value of 0

Comment: if you read the slider API documentation, you can answer these questions yourself: http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/, feel free open new questions if you are stuck somewhere. A reset button can be done with a click handler on any element and something like: $('.slider' ).slider({ value: 0 }); - also if a question is answered and it helped you out, accept it or at least vote it up

Comment: Thanks & sorry for the lack of usage on stack overflow Im still quite new and getting the gist out of it. I read the api and implemented the statement you stated but since the above code is generating the slider in a loop how can implement your reset statement in it ?

Comment: i updated the fiddle for some reset buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/fKUAe/2/. study these snippet and try to understand it. as it seems your a rookie in jquery and/or JS coding, really try to understand each line. im not continuing now from this point. this snippet above works and every additional feature you want to implement should be easy enough if you get it.